# How to call GetAppContext from Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to set up an app, where i update database from broadcast receiver, but when i have class of it, i can't extend AppCompatActivity in which there is getAppContext, needed for database calling, how can i get over it?

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static AppDatabase database;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            database = Room.databaseBuilder(getAppContext(), AppDatabase.class, "mydb").
//get app context is red there, "cant resolve method"

                    allowMainThreadQueries().

                    build();

            UserDAO userDAO = database.getUserDAO();
            User user1 = new User();
            user1.setId(2);
            user1.setName("xDDDD");
            user1.setPassword("1234");
            userDAO.insert(user1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1- Make an Application class MyApplication that extends Application class and use it as global context for your receiver

2- (not guaranteed, you may try) Cast the context parameter that you receive in onReceive method to  AppCompatActivity then call getAppContext

Hint* I don't recommend database code inside the onReceive method. It is better to make another service or intentservice and let the service handle the database code.

Edit:

First create new class in your main package:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Then 
In the Android Manifest file, declare the following.

```
<application android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication">

</application>
```

Now in your `onReceive` method or anywhere you can call MyApplication.getAppContext() to get your application context.

Comment: so how should I do it according to  your ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer with the code for Application class

Comment: Thanks, i edited the code, and it works fine, but i've found another problem, now when it add things to database i deletes all other infos in this database, even when i add another position to this database, it disappears but the thing i added in receiver  doesn't disappear?

Comment: @chester4321 Please mark the my answer as the correct answer. As for the other problem I suggest you post another question with all details. best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getAppContext()` try with `context` like below:

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "mydb").
...
```

**Context** already here which is enough to create and manipulate database.